# Inputting text indefinitely stuck with Selenium Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am trying to input text which is long token(string) into a Text field using following robot framework code (selenium). Here is screenshot where I am entering this token string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n0Kt.png)

```
       1 Element should be enabled  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']
       2 Click Element  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']
       3 Input Text  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']  ${token}
```

But for some reason, execution gets stuck at line 3 and eventually gets timed out (300s). It is able to find the text box element since line 1 and 2, are successful. Any idea how can I resolve this issue? I am using chromedriver.

Sample
`${token}= eyJhbGciOiJSU0ExXzUiLCJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiemlwIjoiREVGIn0.et_wtlu9zrR_u79RvzcgXTdLsPRpYMXB22kH4M5B2nvg9J9yEE_ga0V2zQcwAPrz4g3vBroTKQ21DHByN4v3J2uX0wrkpmIgwF3xwMxKuJCsVZ4-Pf2jZ3ZiJsoKSaivNcPzDW-3VufquJU6ZPRPNzie0NxaQRW-jB1QlO1BqfRjAhTZNBC89xZmqmQZp_CVCm1S3dKY-6fDehx2CQyLgYyjfpUSlwa5TNdKh1EneHbVKqAYaTrJmBoBfk8x68_WyHqCWSrCRE3AxX5X0f27j4JRiuvDMYLDjMPFQMdXzWPH-VqBsY9GG20nsVw-UIxY98ElD2HBzBjRQwoDKzzPv9flxv1Ph_yljT9QkSjBO6iTD_Gd07nk391Rks_jcwTF8hFzIpQ8ImTx1zcntxPkpNFoClAOctQSdeqzgqbWC1KM4P1rncyhVop7T14FVSglVzU2EM7c2QRIoBclW94GvsGtnSXAXzyToQ8QU_qkXdgNQcSxahLfAKhrY3AaXr3y36GFN72J2d7IzO8jYGviAbbKCbUUv7CSVG3NxCThUvrs_yBcBgLpW943iH1ZJp64C1_AIv8JkP3189x7jJJWKk4nw7GW7jEc9DN5JjyDs3nwArvKQ5dyFnqD0aeRKyp5gJW8pyisLIhx2qGGPeMC8GGjCARspFIgLMvczNduaws.7yuAbwzx5nlde8BuWERVKg.fiV9LZdF0KYb3EGO2e5xRP65uy-gnIvByRUK47_JZ8mBqsKzAc8bC-EkDG1U-Ego6h6gEyPoMd5gmA71-fLHfhLlIju4ndCYAlNnRWP0Vt6YrFQYXfGt8YuW9PKA18BFngLElbSGcRo0fjWrp6SsM2QsNAQe2jiyKurRfzb9UOauz7c-kDg2-R3iwSV8ryVqzDT3_10k0hplBSYoChT7cvbNWoIKQ9aksCzYIviGJiGtOqLuY1w7xpwELoDVrsqnulKnJTOhItOzA-PI0pM70nAtAmpOrEb7k9xtol3zQqDWz_M6-2wGxlG1NyD7AQwBjHra_eiqUdCt0FYiCjuTXJjlAaK30_MIdtBdNeSq71UBpCBV_4FUBS12y8SjVgSTgD5BpULretPp43ZaQheKgJYqb1dmBq3FvqLBOTKI200VcY1RCFG8P7pGOJy1vg4L5XEPymwoQUgc8dH3EFmyzBIwwuiEZExrTNupDJeEE5EpO8wFiTDRVy1X-C6n0jt9UtRksquaYmZlKqtUiszTjE20XgMvYEBwvqhXg2n8LXof7xNZah6svw0mhVaU87hkvEixKitmEJaLZX8LK1-3drv2tqwJyCc3umgmJuFif9eCHZ5NRIf_uVDWe88zDZ5hyz5DUXRBxPbJCBKyff1TIv1Cfos_6WEl-azdzC_v3orJcHN8WZJlUdq2JvV0fQyY4MCfkEtGH5lFj3tJik7u9Vg7Jr5le34_kdAoTRmYyFJayuELxH5B4DZkhBAkQI-WbisJ7wjIUJGICf4_qn3AkJamCPZcS1-Sn7Upab_anUwH1AhlvQDuYktKj_LaEbGGNHLyNddf7UexXPYEwdUvldDAhYGvYc9KWGLKeiyOJj71eiWX-YJmeliPLzfGL_t9EoGR6OWIvm8Jy-aJweEYDZPDj5GOfR2mOmdd3kTzn7YLHT4mooSAxdPexv1DBXBrve7iawRBsd9qCc15kyEgWpxSKxLunYO1sFOv-_cIlXmz9gSnlY3aZFMzg0zYAKtmceAxPSE1reydLTHC0aOY-54QDjt3agNcMbOWoscS-9nL-BaPP_YjQnGsQN8mxy5yzf3tF2I5EsBlHwDjz-oCeeMmKIGg1ZUhRc5uBbOFWSKpQyW4lbc8-aJrBbPMG-WmeunHLXX5hwiKNKU2AQV0CiMxfwLu0SoEo34v1g00kHZy8EogSFrHMyBxPrp33xF6H7DUKC7MyU13yg5fQLpVSXPI5n1HGTd7C7LiyweNu6iM1_OQQDXja_1JZKyv_NzgL69BSsUfBwKtGG_XSVc0BPLOIp0TF_7dqioq8PwwHEAJwwMgKT_FMSR7K-yLopZhhAtMFhW5ORhX7HSgpWxxfA00eZijnF0WxobgPe3YYzLD_OLIKwWTgqoUWPByyTr5Uva2tixpo8I64QY2ELvFoLwFfljoxxKTBilT5OwJPzcTMUHfG4vueIoH3e295q-G_4w_f_g0z7c46wG4oSW47aqG_08SAHf_CvxW_li-7UvOLpIE6XXKDPvP1ul0ZEpAKFIe2IYEo_lPjjOD2ztjC_cfatQllL4XRNg-5hLmqVM9zv2xL1rrEScPDMLOA8QhtDBwPkruOQVCo7IFn1Oh6CZQtgF-rhIsmVtKUiiO47Ezozuq6RT0P6IDNIv83lIOSOuHCm2jAV-Pfqxw-OiFJ4kF_y9v8GZa9DO9go2P3hrP4-8b6-2Pf7TSahYBnc_wgr4dOwXE7DTwfyIlwjvq60ilzhRgcMcp6lIAqlK7qtn95p7S2IE6qHyD6FLLBwY8kpH-fjIKwl2hITNE0zbFWbkK9Nl5EwJJJDbYlRqt-nqwnhBH7LIkKj-EYu7bfQYoh5qd5X69sd16uAOZtoaD03D1VQ2CnBS5w3SA95RHjn6uXjLYBsAQ1oiDouS_lHwrTsU-khftokdb8y5qo61nweyD4KlPWS5sqnxzuSLOcDOftehefmRYc_iXlX5a_s1Mh-oiG5MCu60yiw4BpScQUZlmJGBZZSXZa8wPcmbt-DJIIxcWUkAa4A0f0OGYxht-EfAZKcw5oK8-hhQTh7CKgwUPKFvoFHOlM_dRP388VtfxjSFPnMKmschUiJH49Vzkdhsgc6qrCcMQSCLedkKCabNVr7dgsCDMVmT4sP-m4RgtZPBVorx4VSwzEEIvp7-yQtcl3aBkEwuO2STPfIy2fnAbK0h8Z9_GF49jMunx66Q-q1AsNNoZxK-BrdqQY6WWsa0Rf__Ib-we6Ms82g1qrQ.GleGbCAM3mfgjhOzcjnpZA`

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions one by one:

1. Remove line 2 and input text directly.
2. Add sleep after line 1 (for example 3 seconds).
3. After clicking on the token box, inspect the box again and check your selector. (maybe after clicking you should change your selector).
4. Instead of inputting text, paste the token into the box.

Comment: Is there a keyword in robot framework for pasting a text(value from variable)? I didn't see any in documentation?

Comment: There seem to be "Press Keys" keyword, but it takes element locator as the argument, which should work for pasting, but how do I copy the text from variable in this case? ```Press Keys  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']  \\16 ## for paste```

Comment: OK, I was able to copy text using python clipboard library and using ```Copy  ${token}```. But now I am unable to paste the text. Above line for Press Keys, just types ```\\16``` in the text box instead of token value.

Comment: Tried ```Press Keys  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']  CTRL+V``` which seems to be working based on the logs. But probably since I am using Mac, I need to do ```CMD+V```, but its not working, instead it just types CMDV in the field.
```10:00:21.516 INFO Sending key(s) ('CTRL+V',) to xpath=//input[@placeholder='token'] element. ```
```10:00:22.286 INFO Pressing special key CONTROL down. ```
```10:00:22.286 INFO Sending key V ```
```10:00:22.286 INFO Releasing special key CONTROL.```

Comment: Finally, got it working with ```Copy  ${token}
        Press Keys  xpath=//input[@placeholder='token']  COMMAND+V```

Comment: While this works on my mac laptop. I get following error when I run same script on linux/ubuntu machine: ```Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error 
``` Tried aggested fixes listed here like installing xsel, xclip etc. but it is still not working: https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/